# ZeroClipboard events not firing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, zeroclipboard

I am trying to use the latest version of the ZeroClipboard plugin on a page in which the HTML is dynamically generated.  I have tried several different variations of implementing this, but all of them have the same overall effect.  I appear to end up with a page containing the flash elements because when I right-click over the appropriate element, I get the popup "About Flash Player" - but I also see in that same popup "Movie not loaded"

I am using JQuery 1.9.1 and Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.1.  My flash plugin is v11.7.700.202.  My web server is IIS7.5

The code I use to dynamically generate the HTML is in a loop reading an array of user IDs and looks like this:

```
str=str+ '<span class="bMail_address" id=span-"'+
  st.EmailAddresses[i]+
  '" data-clipboard-text="'+
  st.EmailAddresses[i]+
  '@mydomain.com">'+
  st.EmailAddresses[i] +
  "@mydomain.com&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>";
```

After looping through the array and outputtng the resultant string, I then try to add in the ZeroClipboard stuff as follows:-

```
// bind ZeroClipboard
$('.bMail_address').each (function() {
    // read text to copy from the data-clipboard-text attribute
    var msg=$(this).attr('data-clipboard-text');

    //create ZeroCiplboard object
    var clip = new ZeroClipboard();

    // set the text to copy
    clip.setText(msg);

    // setup event handlers
    clip.on('complete', function (client, text) {
        alert("copied: "+text+ "to clipboard");
    });

    clip.on( 'noflash', function ( client, args ) {
        alert("You don't support flash");
    });

    // glue the object to the element   
    clip.glue($(this)); 

});
```

Using the Chrome debugging tools, I can see the iteration through the loop creating new ZeroClipboard objects for all my newly created objects and there are no uncaught exceptions but the alerts never happen so I am presuming the 'complete' event never fires

I'm sure I've made some simple noob mistake, but I just can't see it

All thoughts and suggestions gratefully received

Answer (score 2):

About the flash error: make the "ZeroClipboard.swf" file available to the browser by adding:

```
 `ZeroClipboard.setDefaults( { moviePath: 'http://YOURSERVER/path/ZeroClipboard.swf' } );`
```

see also: https://github.com/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard/blob/master/docs/instructions.md

Second what do you want to add to the clipboard and when?

What (glue this) will be a text and when is a event (b.e. a button click).

Glue() wil add a click event to the dom level element you glue. If the element got a 'data-clipboard-text' its value will be used by glue (you don't have to set it).

Example: add the email address to the clipboard when clicked (a clip will create for each email address):

```
<script>

ZeroClipboard.setDefaults( { moviePath: 'ZeroClipboard-master/ZeroClipboard.swf' } );   

$(function () {

    st = {}
    st.EmailAddresses = Array('test','test2','test3'); 
    $.each(st.EmailAddresses,function(i,emailadres)
    {

      str = '<span class="bMail_address" id=span-"'+
      emailadres+
      '" data-clipboard-text="'+
      emailadres+
      '@mydomain.com">'+
      emailadres +
      "@mydomain.com&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>";

       $('.container').append(str);

    });

    var clip = new Array(); 
    // bind ZeroClipboard
    $('.bMail_address').each (function(i,email) {
    //create ZeroCiplboard object
    clip[i] = new ZeroClipboard();

    clip[i].on('complete', function (client, text) {
    alert("copied: "+ text.text+ " to clipboard");
    });

    clip[i].glue(email); 
    });


})
</script>
```

NOTE: text in the oncomplete function is a object, so use text.text to alert it as a string

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try it over the weekend

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not seem to work, but thanks for the effort, and the code is neater than mine was.

Comment: I can see each "Clip[i]" is created and the options set for the moviePath (same domain, different directory) and the handlers are created within each clip object.  However, the events are not being fired when I click on the movie object in the web page.

The movie object is defintely created because when I right-click I get the "About Adobe Flash Player" menu rather than the usual one for HTML elements

Any ideas on how to further debug this?

Comment: please also read https://github.com/zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard/blob/master/docs/instructions.md `clip[i].on('complete'` will be fired when you left click the clued element (a span containing the email address)

Comment: Thanks again for your time Bass - I have read the documents and the clip entries are definitely glue to the span elements whichcontain the email address, but the event does not appear to be firing because I do not get any alerts.

my code to bind the ZeroClipboard to the email addresses is as you suggested so I am suspecting an issue with the flash object which is  now inserted at the bottom of the page

Comment: my code:

var clip = new Array();
 $('.bMail_address').each (function(i,email) {
  var mov = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host+"/flash/ZeroClipboard.swf";
  ZeroClipboard.setDefaults({ moviePath: mov });
  
  clip[i] = new ZeroClipboard();
  
  clip[i].setText("foobar");
 
  clip[i].on('complete', function (client, text) {
    alert("copied: "+text.text+ "to clipboard");
  });
  
  clip[i].on( 'noflash', function ( client, args ) {
     alert("You don't support flash");
   } );
   
   
  clip[i].glue(email); 
  
 });